# How to create a cursor in X11 from raw data c++

Tags: c++, linux, unix, x11

I have been searching around about this problem for awhile.  I am making a cross platform program and I have figured out how to load an animated cursor with the windows API and how to create a cursor during run time from raw bitmap data.  However I can't find good documentation for this for X11, for my Unix/Linux build of my program.  I know I need to use the XRender extension functions, XRenderCreateCursor and XRenderCreateAnimCursor from this documentation https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libXrender/libXrender.txt but I do not know how to use these functions and the documentation does now show any examples.

Also the raw image data is in the ARGB format, and I want to support the Alpha channel if possible with these cursors.

Could someone show me how to use the X11 and XRender (or XCursor) Library to create a cursor, static and animated, and possibly how to do it so the cursor can be used with any X11 window.

Thanks!

PS.

I am acually editing a open source libary for cross platfrom Gui that I am using for my program, and I am trying to add this feature into the libary but I am not used to programing with X11.

Comment: I strongly suggest using a toolkit like [Qt](http://qt.io). X11 is really complex, you'll need months to master more of it. And it is becoming obsolete (probably replaced by Wayland).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to X, nothing is simple.

First, review the [specification of the X render extension](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/renderproto/renderproto.txt).

The steps for creating an animated cursor are as follows.

1. First, you need to create a `PICTURE` for each frame of the animated cursor, using `CreatePicture`.
2. Use `CreateCursor` to create a `CURSOR` from each `PICTURE`. `CreateCursor` returns a `CURSOR` handle.
3. Then, you take the list of all `CURSOR`s for all of the frames, and then use `CreateAnimCursor` to create a single `CURSOR` representing the animated cursor.

This all comes down to creating a `PICTURE` for each frame. A `PICTURE` is created using `CreatePicture` from a `DRAWABLE` and a `PICTFORMAT`. `DRAWABLE` would be the `PIXMAP` with the actual bitmask for the cursor's frame, and `PICTFORMAT` specifies which channels in the pixmap represent the red, color, and green channels, and must be one of the enumerated `PICTFORMAT`s returned from `QueryPictformat`.

For more information, see the aforementioned X render extension specification.